# After the year or after a year

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

> After a year I'm writing you again. Is this statement correct?

Could I use the definite article before the year or the meaning would be different then?

Comment: After a year is correct. If you say THE year it means that you are referring to a specific year that has been mentioned before or is identifiable by you and the audience.

Comment: Remember that when you write a letter, you write a letter **to** someone. "I'm writing to you again".